# How do I replace spaces with a comma and then a space in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm copying some html into a textarea and trying to format the current textarea from having a div h3, and h3, `<ul> and <li>` tags.

```
// the part being copied and outputs in the textarea like this
<div class="comment" id="comment-11">
     <h3>Comments:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>comment1</li>
         <li>comment2</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

My code:

```
   $(".approve-group").click(function(){
       let id = this.id;
       let num = id.replace(/[^\d]+/, ''); // get the number only
       let comment = $("#comment-"+num).html();
       comment = comment.trim();

       // I'm trying to strip out all the html and make the comment read comment 1, comment 2 and this is the worst part of my code probably where the bug lies.
       comment = comment.replace('Comments:','');
       comment = comment.replace("<h3></h3>","");
       comment = comment.replace("<ul>","");
       comment = comment.replace("</ul>","");
       comment = comment.replace("</li>",",");
       comment = comment.replace("<li>","");
       comment = comment.replace(/ /g, ', '); // this is where the error is.

       $("#loc-comment").val(comment); //copies to my textarea



    });
```

I'm trying to get it to read

```
output: comment1, comment2
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
string = string.replace(/ /g,', ');
```

Error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ,

Thanks guys

Comment: Code works perfectly fine since you edited it: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/qr5fegLj/

Comment: Are you able to post your entire code? If you're having weird errors it may be better to analyse the whole thing. + theres no chance you're missing a closing ';' right ? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't include `let` in front of the second expression, it should work as-is. You can't declare a variable with `let` (or `var`) twice.

Comment: It still doesn't work  with string = string.replace(' ', ', ');  -strange

Comment: Then it sounds like you have some other problem going on. Is there an extra comma somewhere else in your code?

Comment: using string replace will only replace the first instance.. you have to use regex /g to replace all instances, look at Rob's answers

Comment: @GlenK Noted; I've removed the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string = string.replace(/\s/g, ', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it appears to work perfectly fine!

```
var string = "blah blah blah";
var formattedString = string.replace(/ /g, ', ');
```

Comment: Why include script tags, jQuery and reference HTML elements that aren't actually present?

Comment: While you're at it, why not turn it into an actual working snippet? And you don't need jQuery at all here. Keep it simple. The question is moot anyway, since OP's code works fine.

Comment: yeah it works, on there. I'm not sure what's going on. I may have to update my code.

Comment: I've just punched it in as pure JQuery, now you can copy pasta it into https://jsfiddle.net/ with an alert for formattedString to see the result if you like